# QuickBlox Android sample-user application crashes after start. here is Log.

Tags: android, quickblox

```
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 7
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:791)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:757)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:706)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:678)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.quickblox.module.auth.result.QBSessionResult.extractEntity(QBSessionResult.java:49)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.quickblox.module.auth.result.QBSessionResult.processResponse(QBSessionResult.java:34)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.quickblox.internal.core.communication.RestResult.setResponse(RestResult.java:66)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.quickblox.module.auth.result.QBSessionResult.setResponse(QBSessionResult.java:26)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.quickblox.internal.core.communication.Query.completedWithResponse(Query.java:219)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.quickblox.internal.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.handleMessage(HttpRequestRunnable.java:38)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 7
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:339)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:322)
11-06 17:08:28.331: E/AndroidRuntime(32276):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue the json string you trying to parse with `GSON framework`.